# Formal definition of "nearly"

Tags: semantics

When google for "[define nearly](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+nearly)" the provided definition was:

> adverb
>
> 1. very close to; almost.
> 2. closely.

Does this means, despite almost no one use it this way, It is semantically correct to state *"I'm almost 30."* when my actual age is 31?

Comment: It means whatever you can convince your listener that it means.  There is no formal definition or set of rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, neither *nearly* nor *almost* are normally used to indicate you are close to but older than a certain age: with indications of time, they almost exclusively mean "just under x; close to, but under x". Of course there are always exceptions, but this isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

> "I'm almost 30." when my actual age is 31?

it depends on the context of the situation.  Compared to your entire life you are "almost" or "nearly" 31, even if you are 30.  Compared to the smaller situation of the time between 30 and 31. If you are 30 you are not "nearly" 31 because you still have a full year to go.

Comment: nearly/almost thirty means not yet thirty, but near to thirty.